# How to update firestoreConnect (using listener) in React-Redux-Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

How do I force `firestoreConnect` to update? It pulls correctly from Firestore when the component mounts. But after Firestore data changes, it does not fetch the new data. Almost like there is no listener attached. Any ideas?

TodoList.js

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([{
    collection: 'todos'
  }])
)(TodoList)
```

Comment: this looks right. Can you pls provide more code and also which version of react-redux-firebase you are using.

Comment: @mario: It's v.2.2.4

Comment: I cant help you, if you are not going to post more code. :) How are you mapping the state to the props? Maybe there is an issue with the mapping.

Comment: @Mario: I will edit the question to include the details you need. Thanks!